# Session-only cookie for Express.js

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, express

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/cookie.shtml

> Session-only cookies, on the other
>   hand, stores information in the
>   browser memory, and is available for
>   the duration of the browser session.
>   In other words, the data stored inside
>   a session cookie is available from the
>   time of storage until the browser is
>   closed. Moving from page to page
>   during this time does not erase the
>   data.

How can I achieve this using [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js)?

Comment: Would it be more correct to say "from page to page in the same domain"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959233/is-there-a-cookies-based-session-store-for-nodejs-connect-express

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following is what I wanted (sort of). When I close browser the information is gone.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

var MemoryStore = require('connect/middleware/session/memory');
app.use(express.bodyDecoder());
app.use(express.cookieDecoder());

app.get('/remember', function(req, res) {
    res.cookie('rememberme', 'yes', { expires: new Date() - 1, httpOnly: true });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('remember: ' + req.cookies.rememberme);
});

app.listen(4000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: It should also have some sort of server side validation!

Comment: For server-side validation I can just add req.session like ivo's example above!

Answer (score 66):

First off, that website is a horrible place to go.

Now on to the question.

**What sessions actually are:**

- Data is stored on the server side.
- A cookie is issued which contains an ID.
- This ID gets send back to the server on every request, due to the fact that the browser sends the cookies.
- Now the server can re-associate the ID in the cookie - commonly called `Session ID` or short `SID` - with the session data stored on the server.

[Express.js has support for sessions built in](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support).

**What the example shows:**

- Setting up the Express.js middleware
- Using a third-party store for saving the session data, in this case [Redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29) (which IMO is overkill for your problem atm)

Installing Redis requires quite some work, but it's also possible to use Express.js's built-in memory store:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

var MemoryStore = require('connect/middleware/session/memory');
app.use(express.bodyDecoder());
app.use(express.cookieDecoder());
app.use(express.session({ store: new MemoryStore({ reapInterval: 60000 * 10 }) }));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    req.session.visitCount = req.session.visitCount ? req.session.visitCount + 1 : 1;
    res.send('You have visited this page ' + req.session.visitCount + ' times');
});

app.listen(4000);
```

This will simply keep track of how many times you visited the page, closed your browser and re-opend. The counts will still be there.

You can find more on the options of the `MemoryStore`, like maximum life time of a session, etc. [here](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session-memory.html).

Comment: A lot of sites have session only cookies. Even gmail? The 'stay signed' check box is session only? Because I want the user to be logged out when the browser has closed. Because it can be accessed on shared pc and people can forget to press the logout button? I would like to create a 'stay signed in' checkbox? so have both type of sessions. Is this possible? Many thanks.

Comment: P.S: your snippet is not session only cookie, because when you close cooke it will remember count instead setting count to zero again. But I think I know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Ivo, the question was about session only cookie!

Comment: in Ivo's defense, I never heard the term "session-only" to describe the cookie.  Sessions do generally refer to server-maintained information keyed by a generated cookie value, as he described, no?  Is the question different from "how do I expire a cookie when the browser closes"?

Comment: This is not what he asked.
You can have all of your session lying on a signed cookie in a browser... the amount of confusion on NodeJS packages that supposedly do this - but don't actually - is insane - and it's a testament to the lack of basic knowledge from most NodeJS developers

Comment: From [express-sesssion's readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session): "Warning The default server-side session storage, `MemoryStore`, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.

For a list of stores, see compatible session stores."

Answer (score 7):

```
app.use(express.session({cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null }, secret:'eeuqram'}));
```

The above works on IE8, Firefox and Chrome.
The important piece is **maxAge:null**

Comment: Guess you could create a new question(instead)?

Comment: @Alfred, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842389/nodejs-express-session-management-cookie-to-be-session-cookie

Answer (score 2):

```
app.get('/remember', function(req, res) {
   res.cookie('rememberme', 'yes', { expires: 0, httpOnly: true });
 });
```

This will set session cookie. On browser close it will be erased!

Answer (score 1):

Below is the updated code for [Alfred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371178/session-only-cookie-for-express-js/4371696#4371696) (session using Express.js).

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express.createServer();

    var MemoryStore = require('/home/node/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({
        key: 'some-key',
        secret: 'some-We1rD sEEEEEcret!',
        store: new MemoryStore({ reapInterval: 60000 * 10 })
    }));

   app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       req.session.visitCount = req.session.visitCount ? req.session.visitCount + 1 : 1;
       res.send('You have visited this page ' + req.session.visitCount + ' times');
   });

   app.listen(4000);
```

Comment: He doesn't want a MemoryStore - he wants the browser to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I'm adding an answer since all answers here seem to be either outdated, have security flaws or are just plain wrong.

As of now, express uses the `MemoryStore` by default, you don't need to explicitly handle that.

Also, as of now, the express-session's [official readme page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) has a stark warning at the beginning to not use `MemoryStore` as the session store for production, quoting:

> Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.
> For a list of stores, see [compatible session stores](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores).

Here's a simple solution with `connect-mongodb-session` if you want to use MongoDBStore for session storage:

```js
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import ConnectMongoDbSession from 'connect-mongodb-session';

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({
  secret: < COOKIE_SECRET >,
  name: 'sessionId', // Don't use the default name, see http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true, // Remove this if you're not using HTTPS, but it will be a massive security flaw
    sameSite: 'strict',
  },
  store: getStore(),

  // Boilerplate options, see:
  // * https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#resave
  // * https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#saveuninitialized
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

function getStore() {
  const MongoDBStore = ConnectMongoDbSession(session);

  const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: < DATABASE_URI >,
    collection: < SESSION_COLLECTION_NAME >,
    connectionOptions: {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    },
  });

  store.on('error', (error: any) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  return store;
}
```