# How do sessions work in Express.js with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

Using [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js), sessions are dead simple. I'm curious how they actually work though.

Does it store some cookie on the client? If so, where can I find that cookie? If required, how do I decode it?

I basically want to be able to see if a user is logged in, even when the user is not actually on the site at the time (like how facebook knows you're logged in when you're on other sites). But I suppose to understand that I should first understand how sessions work.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I have never used Express.js, although according to [their documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) on the subject it sounds like:

- Cookies are stored on the client, with a key (which the server will use to retrieve the session data) and a hash (which the server will use to make sure the cookie data hasn't been tampered with, so if you try and change a value the cookie will be invalid)
- The session data, as opposed to some frameworks (e.g. [Play Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Framework)!) is held on the server, so the cookie is more like a placeholder for the session than a holder of actual session data.
- From [here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support), it looks like this session data on the server is by default held in memory, although that could be altered to whatever storage form implements the appropriate API.

So if you want to check things without a specific `req` request object, like you said, you need to just access that same storage. On the bottom of the first documentation page, it details required methods the storage needs to implement, so if you're familiar with your storage API, maybe you could execute a `.getAll()` if something like that exists, and loop through the session data and read whatever values you want.

Answer (score 181):

## Overview

Express.js uses a cookie to store a session id (with an encryption signature) in the user's browser and then, on subsequent requests, uses the value of that cookie to retrieve session information stored on the server. This server side storage can be a memory store (default) or any other store which implements the required methods (like [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis/)).

## Details

Express.js/Connect creates a 24-character [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string using `utils.uid(24)` and stores it in `req.sessionID`. This string is then used as the value in a cookie.

### Client Side

Signed cookies are always used for sessions, so the cookie value will have the following format.

```
[sid].[signature]
```

Where [sid] is the sessionID and [signature] is generated by signing [sid] using the secret key provided when initializing the session middleware.
The signing step is done to prevent tampering. It should be computationally infeasable to modify [sid] and then recreate [signature] without knowledge of the secret key used. The session cookie is still vulnerable to theft and reuse, if no modification of [sid] is required.

The name for this cookie is

```
connect.sid
```

### Server Side

If a handler occurs after the `cookieParser` and `session` middleware it will have access to the variable `req.cookies`. This contains a JSON object whose keys are the cookie keys and values are the cookie values. This will contain a key named `connect.sid` and its value will be the signed session identifier.

Here's an example of how to set up a route that will check for the existence of the session cookie on every request and print its value to the console.

```
app.get("/*", function(req, res, next) {

    if(typeof req.cookies['connect.sid'] !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(req.cookies['connect.sid']);
    }

    next(); // Call the next middleware
});
```

You'll also need to make sure the router (`app.use(app.router)`) is included after `cookieParser` and `session` in your configure section.

The following is an example of the data stored internally by Express.js/Connect.

```
{
  "lastAccess": 1343846924959,
  "cookie": {
    "originalMaxAge": 172800000,
    "expires": "2012-08-03T18:48:45.144Z",
    "httpOnly": true,
    "path": "/"
  },
  "user": { 
    "name":"waylon",
    "status":"pro"
  }
}
```

The `user` field is custom. Everything else is part of session management.

The example is from Express 2.5.

Comment: when printing the cookie value with the console.log, it gives the encoded (signed) cookie. how do I get the real information?

Comment: What do u mean by --"The session cookie is still vulnerable to theft and reuse, if no modification of [sid] is required."?  since SID is generated by express ,we can never change it right?

Comment: @WebHrushi I was thinking of a Man-in-the-Middle attack: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack

Comment: Can someone help me with this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982791/opening-password-protected-site-passport-js-with-phantom-js-by-setting-cookie

Comment: how do i create a token for any particular session_id ??

Answer (score 9):

> I'm curious how they actually work though.

Try to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371178/session-only-cookie-for-express-js#4371471) answer and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie) stuff.

> Does it store some cookie on the client?

Yes, it's usually a cookie with assigned session ID, which should be signed with a secret in order to prevent forgery.

> If so, where can I find that cookie? If required, how do I decode it?

You shouldn't mess with a session cookie on the client side. If you want to work with sessions on the server side you should check out related [express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support) and [connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html) docs.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to already excellent answers, here are 2 diagrams I've created to explain Express sessions, their link with cookies and store :

- chocolate cookie:
  [image: chocolate]
- strawberry cookie:
  [image: strawberry]

Diagram's explanation:

> Each cookie has a unique "flavor" (or `sessionId`). When the strawberry cookie is presented to the server (within the HTTP request), the server recognises this flavor and loads from the store the corresponding datas: Rosie's datas, and populates `req.session` with.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't quite get anything from the diagram. What were you trying to convey with/in it?

Comment: @RafaelSofi-zada each cookie has a unique "flavor" (or `sessionId`). When the strawberry cookie is presented to the server (with the HTTP request), the server recognises this flavor and loads from the store the corresponding datas: Rosie's datas, and populates `req.session` with !