# Where does express.session store hashed session key on server side?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cookies, express

I am using mongoStore to manage session on express.js framework.

```
...
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
...
...
app.use(express.session({
    secret:settings.cookieSecret,
    store: new MongoStore({db:settings.db})
}));
...
```

[image: this is the connect.sid and its value]

but here is the record in sessions collection on mongoDB

```
> db.session
s.find()
{ "_id" : "gLQe0NwaSmk9nPu6vOWKuSy0", "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"flash\":{},\"user\":null}", "expires" : ISODate("2013-12-24T05:02:33.308Z") }
{ "_id" : "SoqYLZnEzlVCdj4A1606fDPg", "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"flash\":{},\"user\":\"vvv\"}", "expires" : ISODate("2013-12-24T09:43:55.098Z") }
{ "_id" : "pBtoFt6sR2EvNCuPJVqAFVpR", "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"flash\":{}}", "expires" : ISODate("2013-12-24T09:24:27.846Z") }
{ "_id" : "MEkFGzd190YeJAGDH3nzLT14", "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"flash\":{}}", "expires" : ISODate("2013-12-24T09:44:10.585Z") }
>
```

My understanding is they should store value of connect.id both on client cookie and somewhere on server db or memory. Since I am using connect-mongo, the connect.id should store in db.sessions.

But I can't find the connect.id on server side. Where do they store this value? If my understand is wrong, please correct it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [source code](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/master/lib/connect-mongo.js#L248) of `connect-mongo`, object id of Mongo's document is the session id:

```
var s = {_id: sid, session: this._serialize_session(session)};
```

in [session middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/28e026b8f1839b14f649e7dddf6c161761b1d295/lib/middleware/session.js#L301):

```
// get the sessionID from the cookie
req.sessionID = unsignedCookie;
```

However, you don't just see the cookie ID in your screenshot because a hash is appended to the cookie value (see [this relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522318/2137601)) by the [`cookie-signature` module](https://npmjs.org/package/cookie-signature), hence the `sid.hash` cookie value you're seeing.

Here is the [relevant source code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.11.2/lib/middleware/cookieSession.js#L108-L110), where the hashed value is stored:

```
  // set-cookie
  val = 's:' + signature.sign(val, secret);
  val = cookie.serialize(key, val);
```

You can also read the [unit tests](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.11.2/test/cookieParser.js#L42-L72) for a more thorough understanding.

Answer (score 1):

the session cookie feature of express.js is actually provided by [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect)

the secret key you've set is used to sign the session id from database into the value you see

Check the [source code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/28e026b8f1839b14f649e7dddf6c161761b1d295/lib/utils.js#L137)

Comment: Note that the source you've linked is deprecated: `console.warn('do not use utils.sign(), use https://github.com/visionmedia/node-cookie-signature')`