# How can I get cookie data with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io

* I don't know English well. So understand me please.

I want to use cookie data to get PHPSESSID.
How can I get cookie data?

### server.js

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
  var cookies = socket.handshake.headers.cookie;
  socket.emit("debug", cookies);
});
```

### client.js

```
socket.on("debug", function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

### Console Result

```
connect.sid=s%3AiNWioXwVSG3inLMU6DLHefdB.mS1OBJK6cM%2FXyZSiGBO0%2BMz2jCESsoAmGF9xT9cG52c
```

I will wait some answer.

Comment: One option that i used and its one of a couple options, i converted my sesssions from file based setup to a database setup and used `mysql-node`. Alternatively look into `ExpressJS` info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522020/how-do-sessions-work-in-express-with-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

**server.js**

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    var cookies = socket.handshake.headers['cookie'];
    socket.emit("debug", cookies);
});
```

**on the client.js**

```
socket.on("debug", function(data){
    console.log(data.PHPSESSID);
});
```