# How to use window.sessionstorage in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I store a hash in session storage using javascript like:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('test', true);
```

How do I read this key using node.js?

Comment: you can use it on the front-end such as for React.js, etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't.

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is a browser side API for storing values locally for the life of the browser session, that does not automatically get transmitted to the server. NodeJS is a framework and engine for creating *server* side applications.

Perhaps you're needing the functionality of [cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie).

Comment: you can use it on the front-end for Single Page apps

Answer (score 4):

I have made a simple package to emulate browser's `sessionStorage`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sessionstorage

You can use it like this:

```
const storage = require('node-sessionstorage')

storage.setItem('foo', 'bar')

console.log('item set:', storage.getItem('foo'))
```

Comment: for removing item for session storage?

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing Yes, here are the sources: https://github.com/caffeinum/node-sessionstorage/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 3):

I created this npm package since i'm having the same issue on my own projects,

```
    npm i sessionstorage-for-nodejs
```

again this is my npm package and i created it.

```
    const sessionStorage = require('sessionstorage-for-node');

    sessionStorage.setItem('id', 'value');
 
    console.log('product: ', sessionStorage.getItem('id'));
 
    sessionStorage.removeItem('id', 'value');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `express-session` module on Node.js:

`$ npm install express-session`

But it can be more complicated than the way you use `window.sessionStorage`, e.g. some security needs to be taken care of. For `express-session` documentation, [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session). For more info about how it works, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522020/how-do-sessions-work-in-express-js-with-node-js).