# How to verify routes with JWT token in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authorization, jwt, express-jwt

Dears,

I'm  trying to use JWT tokens to authorize my user. After user and password are confirmed at database, a JWT token is created. I also made a middleware to verify that token and used that middleware at some route that I've created. Testing this route with Postman inserting the token at the header, everything worked fine, but when I'm try to use this at the browser, the token is storage in the login header after I login, but when I redirect (using res.redirect('/dashboard')) I can't access the dashboard page because the token are only at login header, and not at dashboard header.

Do you know how to make that token available at all my environment? Or what's the best way to do that routes authorizations?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: you can use cookies or localStorage

Comment: You can use `passport-jwt`. It's better. Or you can ask me for the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session or cookies and store that token in there and set a time limit of expiry on them.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I never worked with sessions, in fact this is my first web app. I can create a session using 'express-session' and store the token in that session. Is that correct? And if is, I must save the sessionID in some database or it is not required?

Comment: Session IDs can be stored as cookies locally at the client end. You can use a database when you have large number of users, it is considered good practice to store session in a database but not required. When a request is made to the server, the server transmits the cookie containing the session ID.

Comment: But if the user try to use the web app in private mode, cookies by default can not be salved, right? Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: That's what private mode is for. In this mode browser won't store history, cookies, form data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to make your JWT persist on your users' browsers:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('JWT', 'my.jwt.data');
```

Then, get it back using `getItem`:

```
const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('JWT');
```

Comment: According to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495168/how-to-use-window-sessionstorage-in-node-js) I can't use sessionStorage at NodeJS. I tried and failed. Do you think there's a way to make this work with 'express-session'?

Comment: I see. Then, I understand you want to be able to access the JWT in the back end, as it should be present in `req.headers`. It's up to the Front End to send you an `authorization` header (or any similar header), most likely stored in the browser using `localStorage`, where you may access the JWT. Then, you decode it using [jwt.decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtdecodetoken--options).