# Node.js/Express.js session management cookie to be session cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, session-cookies

How can I make the ***connect.sid*** cookie itself only a session cookie instead of a persistent one?

I unsuccessfully tried

```
app.use(express.session({cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true}, secret:'eeuqram'}));
```

But the cookie still had the expiration timestamp.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371178/session-only-cookie-for-express-js

Comment: Actually, that is where I had commented first. I know how to create a session only cookie but I wanted the default cookies created when I am using the session (the default name for that cookie is connect.sid) to be a non-persistent cookie.

Comment: I think you forgot the most important part =>  expires: new Date() - 1?

Comment: "new Date() - 1" wouldn't it be evaluated at nodejs server? If so how'd that relate to what the browser's timezone is? I tried with chrome and it makes the cookie and thus the session expire - and I am left with too many redirects (I am using a SSO solution).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 app.use(express.session({cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null}, secret:'eeuqram'}));
```

The above worked. So by setting maxAge to be null, I did manage expressjs to use session cookies. Phew.

Comment: I guess you should accept your own answer so that topic can be closed.

Comment: I will.. it seems I have to wait for at least 24 hours before accepting my own answer.