# Delete the session on browser close in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

It is possible to delete the session in node js when the browser closes?

I want to have the check that if the user did not select the keep me login checkbox and then closes the window. He should asked to re login.

Answer (score 4):

That's a cookie-specific setting: If you store the session data in a session-only cookie, it will disappear when the browser closes.

See this answer to make a browser-session cookie with express: [Node.js/Express.js session management cookie to be session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842389/nodejs-express-session-management-cookie-to-be-session-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own session delete function on event 'disconnect'

```
socketServer.sockets.on('connection', function onSocket(client) {
    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("disconnect");
        // some code
    });
    -----
});
```

Comment: While this is a potentially useful solution, this is not portable, as not all browsers support websockets. Using cookie settings would be preferable, hence I gave you a -1.