# why is my cookie not being deleted on browser close? (expressJS backend)

Tags: node.js, express

using the following code to set a cookie in my expressJS backend.

Edit The package I am using is 'cookie-session'. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session
I should have specified this my bad. But no setting maxAge to null did not work. The cookie is still there when I reopen the browser.

```
app.use(
cookieSession({
    
    secret: 'secretmonkey',
    secure: false,
    maxAge: null,
    }),
);
```

I read that if maxAge is set to null the cookie should be deleted automatically when browser is closed.

What happens (using chrome) is that the cookie persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842389/

Comment: If it's not clear from the dupe, your `maxAge` and `secure` properties are set on the wrong object. Try `cookie: {maxAge: null}`.

Comment: That is an express.session, I am using cookie-session. And no that did not work. I already said in my question that I did set maxAge to null but the cookie is still there when I reopen the browser

Answer (score 1):

so it turns out I had Chrome open in another desktop on my operating system. So when I was closing the browser it only counted as closing the tab. Chrome was still running after all in the other desktop. Sorry for the silly question, my bad.