# is there a cookies based session store for nodejs (connect, express)?

Tags: node.js, express

in rails the default session store uses cookies. the session is marshaled and signed with a secret key so that client can't temper with it. this approach is very scalable and doesn't require any kind of 'backend' to work.

I can't find anything like that for Express or Connect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [session only cookie for express.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371178/session-only-cookie-for-express-js)

Comment: @jcolebrand - that question is about session-only cookies (related to the lifetime of the cookie), this is about storing session data in the cookie.  Not related at all.

Comment: What are you talking about man? All cookies are about storing data in them. And the whole point is so you don't keep the data in something on the server. I think you need to re-think the strategy. In addition, your comment is unenlightening. Perhaps you mean to do an edit to the question to draw a differentiation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Connect 2x has one built-in and this is an example of how simple it would be to get something basic going with Express 3x https://gist.github.com/1491756 with the new signed cookie support. You can still do the same thing without upgrading but you'll need to use utils instead of those getters

Comment: Thx! Is it now part of express@3.x with http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession ?